html input type NUMBER, pure CSS how to customize plus and minus buttons
I found many ways to customize a html input number, e.g.


 <input name="tgTxt" type="number" value="36.5" max="37" step="0.5" style="width: 160px;">



with non pure CSS.
Is there a way to customize in pure CSS(no jQuery, etc.) the "+" and "-" buttons, so that:

I can make the minus appear to left of the number and the plus to
its right?

I can customize the font-size and background-color of the minus button
independently from the plus button?


So I wish in pure CSS, the minus button to left with a blue background and white font, while the plus button to the right with a red background and white font.
I can do it with other methods, but I'm wondering if it's possible just with input type number.

You can't customise the increment/decrement buttons to that extent, but you can hide them and add your own as pseudoelements. You will be required to then "plug these in" though so it won't be possible to have a purse CSS solution.

https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/04/15/list-of-pseudo-elements-to-style-form-controls/#input_number

You can have some control over it using appearance/wekit-appearance but it is not standardized so you'll probably end up having different behaviour on different browsers

Simply you cannot.
Controls are not style-able cross-browser. The most simple way to do this is use <button> on both sides with + - signs and use a little bit of JavaScript. This will cover the cross-browser compatibility.
Here is an small example. Use CSS to style it the way you want.


/* function take argument how much to add / subtract from current value */

function adjustValue(value) {
  const input = document.getElementById('custom-input');
  input.value = Number(input.value) + value;
}
/* removes the default native browser controls */

input[type="number"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  appearance: textfield;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
<button onclick="adjustValue(-0.5)">-</button>
<input id="custom-input" type="number" />
<button onclick="adjustValue(0.5)">+</button>




Would be even better if it read input.step instead of making consumers enter it twice....
